# Table Cell Spacing previews correct but is larger live

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with two columns and multiple rows.
The table is defined how I wish in regards to border cellpadding and cellspacing

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

While building my preview looks as I wish it would but when I view the page live or in browser all of my cells are blown apart approx 30 - 40 pixels.
I'm not sure if I'm missing something or what the issue is.

Comment: Look to the firebug and find something strange.

Comment: It’s not cell spacing. You need to explain, in directly observable terms, referring to a concrete demo, what you mean. Change `border="0"` to `border="1"` in order to see that it is *not* cell spacing (i.e. spacing between cells) but probably the widths of cells that is the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are building in - sounds like some kind of dreamweaver thingy - but your table is 100% so it should extend the entire width of the container - without seeing your code it's hard to say but if you just dropped it as is in an html page it would extend the width of the browser - meaning it would vary in size as your resized your window.  You may need to set a fixed width on your table - i.e replace 100% with a pixel value such as 600px etc..

Actually other answer mentions using a container of some kind - that's a better idea. Tables have a way of not keeping their width when their content gets larger.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the `width="100%"` that's spreading out the table? Try setting a fixed width on a container div to restrict how far your table is stretched.